Poles and zeros using impulse response coefficients and MATLAB function designfilt
I want to find the poles and zeros of a linear filter which is designed using the following code:  d = designfilt('lowpassiir','DesignMethod','ellip','FilterOrder',3, ... 'PassbandFrequency',0.4,'PassbandRipple',0.5,'StopbandAttenuation',20);
The command zplane(d) gives the below pole-zero plot.

Now, I have only the IR coefficients describing the filter d from the command: coeff1 = impz(d);. How do I obtain the pole-zero plot using these coefficients only? I have tried using zplane(coeff1,1), but that returns the following plot, whereby it considers the linear filter as FIR with 50 coefficients. Could someone explain what is missing here? And how do I get the same pole-zero plot using the coeff1.

In addition to that, the pole-zero plot of zplane(impz(z)) looks like below:

They all represent the same system, however the pole-zero information is different. What am I doing wrong here?

Getting poles and zeros from the impulse response is a tricky problem. The questions here is why? You can get the poles and zeros directly from the filter as [z,p,k] = sos2zp(d.Coefficients); What's wrong with that?

The zeros of the filter are the zeros of the numerator polynomial, and the poles are the zeros of the denominator polynomial. But you don't need to compute the poles and zeros because you can call zplane(b,a), where b and a are the numerator and denominator polynomial coefficients, respectively.
So if you don't want to use zplane(d), you can use zplane with the IIR filter coefficients b and a:

[b,a] = tf(d);
zplane(b,a);

Note that for IIR filters, impz does not compute the filter coefficients, it just returns the first samples of the (infinitely long) impulse response.

thank you Matt. Yes, I used [b,a] = tf(d); [z,p,k] = tf2zp(b,a) to give the pole-zero values. They are the same as in figure 1 in my post. My question is how to obtain the same pole-zero plot using the IR coefficients of the filter d? why coeff1 = impz(d); zplane(coeff1,1) and zplane(impz(z)) are different from the figure 1?

@Neuling: You can also directly use zplane(b,a). The command impz doesn't give you any IIR coefficients, just the first values of the impulse response, so it's doesn't make sense to use these values as an input to zplane.

b and a ARE the filter coefficients of an IIR filter.

The pole-zero information is the same using inverse frequency response function in matlab. The numz, denz of true filter is same as the coefficients b,a below.
d = designfilt('lowpassiir','DesignMethod','ellip','FilterOrder',3,…
'PassbandFrequency',0.4,'PassbandRipple',0.5,'StopbandAttenuation',20);
coeff1 = impz(d);
[numz,denz] = tf(d);
nb = 3; na = 3;
[H, w] = freqz(coeff1,1,length(coeff1));
[b, a] = invfreqz(H, w, nb, na);


For IIR filters impz is just useful if you want to know the (first part of the) impulse response. Don't use it for anything else, because the actual impulse response is of course infinitely long, so computing the frequency response from impz will only give you a rather crude approximation.

'invfreqz()' is tricky especially if you don't know the filter order. You often run into "matrix is poorly conditioned" problems.

With zplane(d) you obtain zeros and poles
hzp=zplane(d)

With [b,a]=freqz(d) you get b and a coefficients
One can also build filters with the DSP tool box
iir = dsp.IIRFilter('Numerator',b,'Denominator',a);

